# The name on the security certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the server

Tags: outlook, certificate, exchange-server, invalidation

using a self signed certificate in Exchange 2010, Error displays in Outlook 2013 ( image is Microsoft example)

[image: Example of error (from Microsoft site)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.howtogeek.com/107415/it-how-to-create-a-self-signed-security-ssl-certificate-and-deploy-it-to-client-machines/

Shows a clear nice well explained answer how to do this. Works perfect.